How to run a bash script using bash using Docker-in-Docker
I have a bash script that I use to build my Docker images and I'm trying to set up my GitLab CI so that it automatically builds the image whenever I push a tag.
This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:
stages:
  - build

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
  CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: "true"
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

build:
  image: docker:27.1.0
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:27.1.0-dind
  before_script:
    - echo '>>>>> DEBUG - install bash'
    - apk add bash
  script:
    - echo '>>>>> DEBUG - build the images'
    - source dockerbuild.sh -t latest
  only:
    - tags

I believe dind uses sh instead of bash so I went and installed it first (I need bash to run my script not sh) but I'm getting the following issues:
$ apk add bash
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing readline (8.2.10-r0)
(2/2) Installing bash (5.2.26-r0)
Executing bash-5.2.26-r0.post-install
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r29.trigger
OK: 44 MiB in 75 packages
$ echo '>>>>> DEBUG - build the images'
>>>>> DEBUG - build the images
$ source dockerbuild.sh -t latest
/bin/sh: dockerbuild.sh: line 6: syntax error: bad substitution
/bin/sh: dockerbuild.sh: line 51: pushd: not found

The lines mentioned in the errors are:
# Line 6
GIT_VERSION=$(git describe --tags --always --dirty)

# Line 51
pushd $LOCATION >/dev/null


I am aware that the script is still being run using sh based on the error (/bin/sh). I'm not sure how to switch it over to bash.

Can you avoid unnecessary bashisms; for example, use POSIX standard . instead of bash-extension source, and use cd instead of pushd?  This doesn't specifically seem to be about a DinD setup, except as GitLab uses it.

source runs it within the current shell, which you already know is not bash. you need to start a new shell to run it. Just do bash dockerbuild.sh instead of source dockerbuild.sh.

Also, the $(...) syntax is POSIX standard and works just fine in the /bin/sh that comes in the DinD container. There's something else wrong with your script to trigger the error.

Thank you @MarkReed, I did bash dockerbuild.sh and it worked.

I can think of a few possible remediations

Put a #!/path/to/bash at the beginning of your script

Write two scripts, one that does what you need and one that calls it with bash

Change your script to use the old "sh" syntax, so $(command) would translate to `command` and write some logic to absolve yourself of pushd behavior. In general, it's best to write your code so the current directory is not important, i.e. specify full paths for everything


Edit: 4. You should be able to override the entrypoint/cmd of the container. Too little information in your post to offer much more help in that direction, so bust open some docs.


I already put #!/bin/bash at the top of my script. 2. Isn't it the same as the source dockerbuild.sh -t latest which I thought would call the script using the newly installed bash? 3. I'd rather stick to bash if I could help it.



Okay, then the script is explicitly being called with sh, so that won't work, 2. no, source is different, read the docs, it expressly does what you do NOT want it to do. Use: /path/to/bash /path/to/script to execute your script with bash, 3. I understand not wanting to resort to old syntax, but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

